# how to write the code read one by one TextView , how to store the sd card

Tags: android

This is my code: how to write the java code display the one by one textview ,for example click the submit button display the text view and store And next time click the same button display the next text view and store the data.how write this type of java code,I have a main .xml file

```
public class XMLRWActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
Button submit_btn =  (Button) findViewById (R.id.submit_btn);
final EditText textbox = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.first_text);
final TextView newtext = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.read_text);

submit_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
            byte[] readinfo = new byte[160];
            String FILENAME = "first_file";
        FileOutputStream mystream;
    try {
        mystream = openFileOutput (FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String variabletowrite = textbox.getText().toString();

        mystream.write(variabletowrite.getBytes());
        mystream.close();
        FileInputStream readstream = openFileInput (FILENAME);
        readstream.read(readinfo);
        newtext.setText(new String(readinfo));


        readstream.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
   });
   }
 }
```

This is a main.xml file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:weightSum="1">
<TextView  
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="@string/hello"
/>
<EditText android:id="@+id/first_text"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<requestFocus></requestFocus>
</EditText>
<Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="Submit"     
android:id="@+id/submit_btn" 
 android:layout_width="match_parent" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/read_text1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="TextView1"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" ></TextView>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/read_text2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="TextView2"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" ></TextView>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/read_text3"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="TextView3"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" >

 </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is a storage permission in manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" > </uses-permission>
```

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. Android Stack Exchange is for enthusiasts, power users, and regular people who use the Android operating system. Questions about developing/programming for Android is off-topic here, please ask these questions on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use listview

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnItemSelectedListener
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

```
private static String[] data = new String[]
{ "aaaa", "bbbbbb", "ccccc", "ddddd", "eeee", "ffffff", "gggggg ", "hhhhhhhhhhh", "iiiiiiiiii", "jjjjjjjjjjj" };

private ListView lvDynamic;
private ViewAdapter viewAdapter;

private class ViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private Context context;
    private List textIdList = new ArrayList();

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        String inflater = Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE;
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(inflater);
        LinearLayout linearLayout = null;
        if (textIdList.get(position) instanceof String)
        {
            linearLayout = (LinearLayout) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.text, null);
            TextView textView = ((TextView) linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.textview));
            textView.setText(String.valueOf(textIdList.get(position)));
        }
        return linearLayout;
    }

    public ViewAdapter(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return textIdList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        return textIdList.get(position);
    }

    public void addText(String text)
    {
        textIdList.add(text);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }
}


@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id)
{
    id = position;

}

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    lvDynamic = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvDynamic);
    Button btnAddText = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAddText);

    btnAddText.setOnClickListener(this);

    viewAdapter = new ViewAdapter(this);
    lvDynamic.setAdapter(viewAdapter);
    lvDynamic.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}


public void onClick(View v)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int randomNum = new Random().nextInt(data.length);
    viewAdapter.addText(data[randomNum]);
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Comment: i want to xml file also ,i don not understand